# Make keyboard get above UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I coded an UIWebView inside an UIAlertView, and would like the user to type something inside that webView. Unfortunately, my keyboard got covered by the AlertView.
Is there anyway to make the keyboard cover the view, not otherwise?

Comment: Why would you put a web view inside an alert??

Comment: But seriously--there may be a better way to accomplish what you want to do. If you tell us what you're doing, we can give you better help.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan. Please provide us more information on what you are trying to do. The first thing that strikes is that it's so weird to have a UIWebView inside an UIAlertView. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add observer for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification. And when it is displayed - simply find the keyboard inside the view hierarchy. Look [here](https://gist.github.com/454844) for an example. When you find it - bring it to front (maybe, do the same for keyboard parent view/views).

As far as I remember, this works only with iOS 4.0+.

And once again - listen to Jonathan Grynspan & Legolas - better think about another way of accomplishing your task.